# Access variable in try block

Tags: java, scoping

I want to remove the `throws FileNotFoundException` from the method head and put it into it.

```
public static String[] read(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

But then I can't access `in` (the scanner) anymore! How to handle that?

```
public static String[] read(String file) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    // ...
    in.close();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `in` is out of scope outside the `try` block. You can either do this:

```
public static String[] read(String file) {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    finally() {
        in.close();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or better yet, try with resources

```
public static String[] read(String file) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file))){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        // whatever comes next
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
        
    // right here, the scanner object will be already closed
    return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use try-with-resources so you dont have to worry about closing the scanner object.

```java
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file))) {
        //Your code
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use try with ressource, that permit to close automaticaly your in.

like that

```
   Scanner in ;
   try ( in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file))) {
  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` variable is locally scoped to the `try` block. You can either declared the variable before the `try` block, *or* close `in` within the `try` block. There's not much use in closing it if it never successfully opened.